# can turtles be dressed like the ninja turtles

Tags: turtles, ethics

I am looking into getting 4 turtles and liek the idea of them having small coloured bands to represent which ninja turtle they are named after, not sure how I would do this and also not sure whether it would be ok in regards to the ethics and safty of sed turtle.

Thanks,
Turtlelover69

Comment: @Allerleirauh Please consider converting this to an answer. This would make a good answer, you wouldn't even need to add more information. Although I'd be very interested in a picture or a link to either a turtle safe paint or a turtle painted like that.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find a species of turtle, which are okay to live together. Red ear sliders for example are loners and would suffer with 4 together in one enclosure.

Then you need to find a color (imagine it like nail polish) which does not give chemicals to the organism. This you could use to paint the band onto their upper shell. I saw others use turtle friendly color to write their names or phone number onto the shell, to get the turtle back, if it breaks from the garden enclosure.

- [article](https://www.cbsnews.com/dfw/news/dont-paint-turtles-with-nail-polish/) about the risks of coloring tortoises: paint will decrease the abability of the shell to use sun rays to produce vitamin D (very important for healthy and strong shell and bones). So I would recomment to paint as less space as possible, a small line may be okay.
- [method paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322807915_CLBMON-11B3_Revelstoke_Reach_Painted_Turtle_Monitoring_Program_Annual_Report_-_2015) about tracking turtles: "Juvenile turtles were marked with either a transmitter or using dots of water-based
  nail polish applied to the middle of the costal and vertebral scutes of the carapace
  (Figure 4-2)"(page 12)

[image: scheme of marking turtles]